# android.database.Cursor : class or interface?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Ok I'm just a little confused about this...I know in standard Java even that an interface is just something you specify methods in. So I'm surprised now to see that tutorial code I'm trying to test uses (and even instantiates) Cursor which is an interface according to developer.android.com
So, what, can interfaces actually have methods defined in them? I thought not..
On a side note, I would be much obliged if someone would take a new look at my previous question here : [Problems with simple SQLite test in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027767/problems-with-simple-sqlite-test-in-android). Please be sure to read the comments as well if you are going to look at it.

Comment: Unless you point out what tutorials you are referring to there's no way to answer that question. I'm pretty sure the tutorials use Cursor implementations and not just the Cursor interface and the implementations will have code it them...

Comment: Oh my bad I slightly misinterpreted the code in question...>__>
It's not instantiating, it's just used as a type.

Comment: "can interfaces actually have methods defined in them?" ever heard of inheritance? Once class ``B`` implements interface ``A``, ``B`` can be casted to ``A``. So if ``Cursor`` is actually interface, that's really awesome because it leaves space for other developers to extend such interface and implement the methods their way, by respecting the interface defined in ``Cursor``. This means your code doesn't need to change because it uses the interface specified by ``Cursor`` which doesn't change.

Comment: Yes I know what inheritance is...I guess defined is the wrong word to use. To equate my question's wording to yours: specify = define, define = implement